# How can I execute a TagHelper by Environment in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, configurationmanager, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm leaving `todo:` comments/notes/questions to for my UX designer and Product Owner in our Dev environment; I've created a `TodoTagHelper` that makes this really easy, e.g.:

```
<todo>need to make this a search field</todo>
```

They like it, I like it, but I don't want to miss one and have it show up in Production; therefore, I'd like to change the output based on the environment.

How can I access the Configuration from within the TagHelper so I can remove the output if I'm not in Dev?  My guess is to add it to the `services` collection in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, but I'm not sure what scope I should use... or even if it's already accessible somewhere else.

Comment: Why not use the existing `<environment>` tag-helper rather than inventing your own?

Comment: Yeah, I could wrap the `<todo>` in an `<environment>` but I was hoping to make it cleaner and quicker to add the `<todo>`s.  If the TagHelper could handle it, I won't forget to wrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject `IHostingEnvironment` directly into your `TodoTagHelper`'s constructor, and use that to get the current environment name (or check for Development by calling `IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()`).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.